# Disable alert message with internet connectivity off

Tags: message-coding

I work in an environment that has mathematica's internet connectivity turned off under Help > Internet Connectivity. Recently, after installing mathematica 10.0, every time mathematica is loaded it complains about internet connectivity and put up messages saying

```
PacletInstall::offline: The Wolfram System cannot install paclet WolframAutoUpdate because it is currently configured not to use the Internet for paclet downloads. To allow internet access, use Help > Internet Connectivity....
```

is there a way to disable such alerts/disable the auto update?

Comment: Have you tried [Off](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html)?

Comment: @belisarius this message is printed right after mathematica is launched, before I've entered anything, so `Off` does not apply here.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this problem so I can't test a solution, but try putting `Off[PacletInstall::offline]` in your `kernel/init.m` file; it may load soon enough to have effect.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but what OS are you using?

Comment: @KellenMyers I'm on windows, current I resort to setting a dummy proxy 0.0.0.0:80 that goes no where to temporarily fix this warning.

Comment: I have the same problem also. But it is a harmless beep that shows up only at start time, so it was easier to just ignore it than try to find how to turn it off :)

Comment: Just allow automatic updates and restart Mathematica once. After that you can disable internet connectivity again and there will be no pop-ups appearing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard suggestion works.

Comment: @pepper_chico Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score -4):

It is correct! Follow these steps:

1. Enable Internet Connectivity in Preferences.
2. Allow automatic updates.
3. Restart Mathematica.
4. Disable Internet.
5. Restart Mathematica.

Et Voila'!

Comment: It wasn't me but you get downvote, probably, because it does exactly the oposite that OP want's. At least this is my interpretation, so: OP **needs** Internet while wants **I Conn** to be false.