# Turn off a message forever?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

I am using Mathematica on an offline PC. I constantly get the message `PacletInstall::Offline` at startup. Is there a way to turn off this message forever?

I know how to turn it off within one session. I want the setting to last between sessions.

Comment: [Related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58415)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the command to turn off the message in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Kernel", "init.m"}]` file and save it. This file is loaded automatically every time the kernel starts.

Comment: Just for completeness, the command to add is: `Off[PacletInstall::offline]`